# Route Not Found Exception Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my Laravel 7.0 project, though I have `login` routes but still application gives an error

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
> Route [login] not defined.

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function() {
Route::get('/', 'AuthController@home');
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@index');
Route::post('post-login', 'AuthController@postLogin'); 
Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::resource('mobile-series', 'MobileSeriesController');
Route::get('mobile-series-status-update/{id}', 'MobileSeriesController@statusUpdate');
Route::resource('mobile_series_versions', 'MobileSeriesVersionController');
});
```

I have also applied
`Route::post('login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@index']);`

But after using this my application gives error

`This page isn’t working. localhost redirected you too many times.`

How to solve this? Anybody help please?

Comment: None of your routes have `->name('login')`, so the error is correct. If you want to use named routes, you need to actually name your routes. Also, when you changed your code, you changed the `POST` route to `login` from `post-login`, which might have caused your infinite redirection loop.

Comment: @GazmendSahiti..I have used laravel authentication. All was perfect. But my logout route was not working. After that I add middleware in the group route. and from that time I got this "Route [login] not defined"

Comment: @TimLewis...If I use `->name('login')`....also get error `This page isn’t working. localhost redirected you too many times.`

Comment: That means you have an infinite redirect happening somewhere. Did you try moving your `login` and `post-login` routes *outside* of this Authentication middleware? Right now, you're saying "To access the login route, you need to be authenticated (logged-in)"; that's impossible, and your code is trying to tell you that.

Comment: @TimLewis....I have tried like this now.....now login portion is ok.... but while trying to access others routes inside middleware, that time getting the same error `Route [login] not defined.`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71559209/edit) and include more details. Your code should work fine if you A) add `->name('login')` to whatever route should be named `login`, and B) you move `Route::get('login')` and `Route::post('post-login')` outside of the `Route::prefix()->group()`. Beyond that, run `php artisan routes:list` to see your routes and their names. If there isn't a `login` named route there, then there's still something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting an overview of all your routes using this command `php artisan route:list`.
Normally I believe your routes should look like this;

```
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@index')->name('login'); OR
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
```